# Header injection through browser

Tags: java, security, header, request

I have a clustered application with 7 servers.

The application uses load balancer to redirect the user to a server.

For the authentication it uses SiteMinder.

For the authentication we look into the request **req.getHeader("HEADER_NAME")**

The header name is passed to the application by SiteMinder and the user is authenticated.

When we use the load balancer URL it works fine with the authentication because SiteMinder takes care of any possible injection.

But when we use a specific Server URL, we can inject any header (by example using Modify Headers in Firefox) and that is the problem.

is there a way to identify if the header was injected?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the header you are looking up only contains the username of the authenticated user, No, you cannot identify that the header was injected as it will look exactly the same to the server as if SiteMinder had added it.

If there are any options to encrypt, hash or sign the header then this would be a valid method of checking for tampering.

Failing this, you could restrict access to the direct server URLs so they are only accessible to the Load Balancer with Site Minder running. To achieve this you wouldn't route public IPs to the servers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to recognise that the header was injected.. You can use one of two optinons:

1. As SilverlightFox suggested encrypt the user id instead of sending the header as plain text. You can do this by using the ActiveResponse feature of SiteMinder that allows you to inject a Java class which generates the header value.
2. The other simpler option is to define a shared secret between the application and the SiteMinder setup. You could then ensure that the shared secret is also sent as a header along with user id etc. If the shared secret string is not sent/does not match, the request can be rejected. 
   This is not as secure as the first option but, assuming that you have decent security policies (restricted access to servers/SM configuration, direct access to server URLs only allowed to admins etc.) this should suffice.

However, if you are not very sure of the security processes it would be better to use the first option.

Hope this helps.